# OpenCV and Alglib Random Forest classifiers Comparison

Tags: c++, opencv, classification, alglib

Previously I used Opencv random forest classifier for my data. But problem with Opencv is posterior probabilities. It is just for binary classification and does not support more than two classes probabilities (`CvRTrees::predict_prob opencv` function). While the number of classes I have in my data is 7. But ALGLIB support more than two probabilities (`alglib::dfprocess`). I used this function to get probabilities for my seven classes. But problem with me is now the results I obtained with Alglib are much poor than OPencv classifier.

Can anybody tell me how can I solve my problem ? I need to get probability prediction for all the seven classes which I am using.